# How many instances have been created when we call activity using intent again n again without finishing it in android?

Tags: android, android-activity

In my activity A I am calling activity B using Intent. In Activity B I have override onBackPressed() and from that I am calling Activity A, but not use finish(). So again from A when we call activity B, does same instance of activity B is used or new instance is created? 
And Is it bad idea to call again n again without finishing activity? If it is, how to prevent creating new instance of activity B every time? Does android:launchMode="singleTask" in manifest will help or not in this case?

Comment: Yes android:launchMode="singleTask" will help you. for more http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set **FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT** flag in intent before calling the activity. this flag will cause the launched activity to be brought to the front of its task's history stack if it is already running, so that no new instance of that activity will be created. for e.g.

```
Intent settingIntent = new Intent(ActivityA.this, ActivityB.class);                         
settingIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
ActivityA.this.startActivity(settingIntent);
```

Comment: But oncreate() method is not called if we use above code when we call activity B again..Any reason?

Comment: yes because by setting this flag your already launched activity will be brought to the front from activity stack. and onCreate is called only when activity is newly launched. this code will launch the activity for the first time if it is not available in activity stack, so onCreate will be called only first time but then onwards whenever you launch this activity by setting this flag it will check if it is already launched or not.and use that existing activity. but you can use "onPause" and "onResume" methods of that activity to handle your variables.